# Why does a recursive function returns this value?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to understand why does the recursive function returns 1003 instead of 1005.

```
l = [1,2,3]
def sum(l):
    x, *y = l
    return x + sum(y) if y else 1000

sum(l)
```

According to [pythontutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html) the last value of `y` list is 5 and that would make return value `1000 + sum([2,3])` 1005, am I correct?

[image]

Comment: what is this syntax: `x, *y = l`? is it python 3?

Comment: @Elisha it will unpack the rest of l to y.

Comment: I guessed that, but it does not work on python2.7. I think it is better to add `python3` tag

Comment: @Elisha `x, *y = seq` will iterate over the sequence, put the first element in `x` and all other elements (even none) in a list and assign this list to `y`. It would be cool if `y` was just an iterable and the unpacking was lazy, however this complicates handling things like `x, *y, last = sequence`.

Comment: @Elisha: It's allowed as of python 2.7, I think. And anyway, as 3 is the most recent version, it's only natural to assume 3 is used.

Comment: It would also be better to link to Python Tutor's 3.3 visualizer instead of its 2.7 visualizer. Or, better, include a link [with your actual code](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=l+%3D+%5B1,2,3%5D%0Adef+sum(l)%3A%0A++++x,+*y+%3D+l%0A++++return+x+%2B+sum(y)+if+y+else+1000%0A%0Asum(l)&mode=display&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&drawParentPointers=false&textReferences=false&showOnlyOutputs=false&py=3&curInstr=0).

Comment: @Noctua: No, it's not allowed in 2.7.

Comment: @abarnert: Ah yes, I checked, it's 3.x. But it's awesome, everyone should use it.

Comment: I was just going to comment and say that the `return`/`if` does something other than you think :) But others did that already. So, Just remember this: `IF x THEN y` is normal. `y IF x` is reversed syntax. The IF on the end of the line applies to WHOLE line/expression that precedes it. Hence, in `return...if..` the `return` keyword is "under" that if, not the other way. So, you need parenthesis to limit its effect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> According to pythontutor the last value of y list is 5 and that would make return value `1000 + sum([2,3])` 1005, am I correct?

No, the last value of `y` is `[]`. It's never anything but a list, and besides, there are no `5`s for it to ever be. On top of that, the recursive return value is always on the right of the `+`, only the `x` is ever on the left.

Let's step through it:

```
sum([1, 2, 3]) = 1 + sum([2, 3])
sum([2, 3]) = 2 + sum([3])
sum([3]) = 1000
```

So, substituting back:

```
sum([2, 3]) = 2 + 1000 = 1002
sum([1, 2, 3] = 1 + 1002 = 1003
```

The problem is that when `y` is empty, you're returning `1000`, not `x + 1000`.

Your confusion may just be a matter of precedence. Maybe you expected this:

```
return x + sum(y) if y else 1000
```

… to mean this:

```
return x + (sum(y) if y else 1000)
```

… but actually, it means this:

```
return (x + sum(y)) if y else 1000
```

Answer (score 2):

Recursion step by step

1) `x = 1` `y = [2,3]`

2) `x = 2` `y = [3]`

3) `x = 3` `y = []`

Note that step 3) returns `1000` since `not y`. This is because your return statement is equivalent to

```
(x + sum(y)) if y else 1000
```

Thus we have

3) `1000`

2) `1000 + 2`

1) `1002 + 1`

The result is `1003`.

So perhaps what you are looking for is:

```
return x + sum(y) if y else 1000 + x
```

or (copied from ndpu's answer):

```
return x + (sum(y) if y else 1000)
```

(take `x` into account in last step)

Comment: What I don't understand is how `x` becomes `3` eventually. Because at every iteration we have `x` being reassigned to the next `l` value. `x` is being raised to `3`. How can the function remember the `x` value?

Comment: and why do we have 1000 + 2 and 1002 + 1 at step 2) and 1) accordingly? I thought we should be getting just 2 and 1 since `else` condition is not triggered at that stage.

Comment: @minerals It's a recursion. Value in step 2 is a value from step 3 (i.e. 1000) + x which is 2. Value in step 1 is a value from step 2, i.e. 1002 + x which is 1. As for the first question: In the third step you call `sum([3])` so `x, *y = [3]` produces `x=3` and `y=[]`. I'm not sure what you mean by "raised to `3`".

Comment: I see, looks like I do not fully understand recursion. It makes sense now.

Answer (score 2):

You should add parentheses:

```
l = [1,2,3]
def sum(l):
    x, *y = l
    return x + (sum(y) if y else 1000)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try to use a debugger or actually print things inside the function. Without executing the code I guess that it should be something like this:

```
l = [1,2,3]
def sum(l):
    x, *y = l
    return x + sum(y) if y else 1000

sum(l)
```

It will call a such:

```
-> sum([1,2,3])
x : 1
y : [2, 3]
-> sum([2, 3])
x: 2
y: [3]
-> sum([3])
x: 3
y: []
returns 1000
returns 2 + 1000
returns 1 + 1002
```

Comment: He already tried to use an interactive step-by-step visualizer, and couldn't understand what it was showing him; I'm not sure a `pdb`-style debugger, which has the same information in a less novice-approachable way, is going to help…